# How to mouseclick into other application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to send mouseclick down and mouseclick up. i got unexpected result. the mouseclick down message works if i remove mouseclick up message. the button inside application still hold the button. it needs to release to do some action. but the release not work. i follow log from spy++, after test 1 by 1 line. i test it only need 2 message. WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP. cause i see the button still hold.

1. S WM_NCHITTEST xPos:1485 yPos:755
2. R WM_NCHITTEST nHittest:HTCLIENT
3. S WM_MOUSEACTIVATE hwndTopLevel:000504BA nHittest:HTCLIENT
   uMsg:WM_LBUTTONDOWN
4. R WM_MOUSEACTIVATE fuActivate:MA_ACTIVATE
5. S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0000004553CCEA70
6. R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
7. S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED lpwp:0000004553CCEA70
8. R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED
9. S WM_ACTIVATEAPP fActive:True dwThreadID:00000000
10. R WM_ACTIVATEAPP
11. S WM_NCACTIVATE fActive:True
12. R WM_NCACTIVATE
13. S WM_ACTIVATE fActive:WA_CLICKACTIVE fMinimized:False
    hwndPrevious:(null)
14. S WM_IME_SETCONTEXT fSet:1 iShow:C000000F
15. S WM_IME_NOTIFY dwCommand:IMN_OPENSTATUSWINDOW dwCommand:00000002
    dwData:00000000
16. R WM_IME_NOTIFY
17. R WM_IME_SETCONTEXT
18. S WM_SETFOCUS hwndLoseFocus:(null)
19. R WM_SETFOCUS
20. R WM_ACTIVATE
21. S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:000504BA nHittest:HTCLIENT
    wMouseMsg:WM_LBUTTONDOWN
22. R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False
23. P WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:1240 yPos:697
24. P WM_MOUSEMOVE fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:1240 yPos:697
25. S WM_NCHITTEST xPos:1485 yPos:755
26. R WM_NCHITTEST nHittest:HTCLIENT
27. P WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:0000 xPos:1240 yPos:697
28. S WM_CAPTURECHANGED hwndNewCapture:00000000
29. R WM_CAPTURECHANGED

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow("AppliationWindow", "Application1");

    if(hWnd != NULL)
    {
      std::cout << "Found";
    }else{
      std::cout << "It's not found";
    };

    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(1240, 697));

    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(1240, 697));

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). Same principles apply to mouse input. Whatever your problem this is not a solution.

Comment: @IInspectable i dont know what u means. in this application, i can send keystroke without problem. but the problem here, i need to send mouseinput in background. WM_LBUTTONUP message not works wheras WM_LBUTTONDOWN works. i checked when i run my application. i see same message as capture by spy++.

Comment: @IInspectable i found out. WM_LBUTTONUP works. but the action not work. I add Sleep function to check. It push and release. but no action. it just click and release. exactly when  that button click new dialog window will showup. i check spy++ theres no other message again after lbuttondown and lbuttonup. whats wrong here? the application i try to simulate is base on unity application.

Comment: You cannot do this. If you need to simulate input, use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput). If you need to automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: @IInspectable i test sendinput, it need to bring application to foreground. how to set application to background again when i done? i know to bring to foreground with SetForegroundWindow.

Comment: `SendInput` is most likely not what you want to be using. There's essentially only a single use-case for it: Writing a virtual keyboard or mouse. It's distinctly not an applicable solution to UI Automation. Since you are talking about pressing a button, why not have UI Automation do it for you?

Comment: @IInspectable i'm not sure it will work with unity game. i ever test it before. unity application game have own client area calls unity player.

Comment: Games, especially high performance games, tend to operate with user input at a lower hardware level, using Raw Input API, custom/direct driver access, etc.  So UI Automation may not work in this case, either.

Comment: @RemyLebeau in my case, use winapi message. it works. WM_LBUTTONDOWN works. the problem is WM_LBUTTONUP. lose focus in client area before release left button. But the weird i check my application message that send to unity application. the message same as manual click. but, i think WM_LBUTTONUP lose focus.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned,the WM_LBUTTONUP message does not set focus to the window. If you want to get the focus,  you will need to use the `SetForegroundWindow` function to set whatever window it is back to the foreground and then send the `WM_SETFOCUS` window message to set the focus back to the whatever window it is.

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation, for a window to recieve a WM_LBUTTONUP message, it has to capture the mouse input previously. So you must make the window capture the mouse input somehow. But I don't recommend this method.

Comment: That's not what the documentation says. Besides, the documentation is referring to normal input processing. It makes no statements about the effects of a program posting fake messages.

Comment: @IInspectable You may be right. Sorry all for this mistake.

Comment: That conclusion is wrong. It's the window manager that determines the window that should receive messages as a result of input processing, and then posts the input messages to the respective window's input queue. The window manager does **nothing** when a message gets posted by other code.

Comment: @IInspectable But why isn't the WM_LBUTTONUP message being sent?

Comment: WM_LBUTTONUP  is being posted but not in a way that is acceptable by the other program.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an internal mechanism that the Window Manager and **related functions** should follow in a common sense?

Comment: The window manager doesn't fix things up once you have stopped using common sense. [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903) explains some fundamentals of input processing. There's literally nothing the window manager **could** do when a rogue application starts posting fake input messages. The core issue here is, that people seem to grossly underestimate the amount of skills required to cheat well in games.

Comment: @IInspectable so WM_LBUTTONUP post succefully. but anti-cheat shield fake that input?  rogue application = anti-cheat shield? the anti-cheat shield intercept input message before send to real game application?

in link u give, it explain re-ordering message. its not my case. i checks input message that my application give. it order exactly. wm_lbuttondown first then wm_lbuttonup.

Comment: @IInspectable i check how click up mouse works. button down and button up position should same. i think there's trick inside nchittest. cause the coodinate different from message button down and up. i delay 10 seconds my click. i see long nchittest. when i click. totally different coordinate.

Comment: I doubt that you're running into any sort of anti-cheat infrastructure. It's more likely that the target application simply doesn't care about messages posted in response to input processing. Games usually handle input at a much lower level in the system. By *"rogue application"* I am referring to any program that doesn't follow documented contracts (such as your program). Now here's the truth you don't want to hear: Writing a game cheat is **significantly** harder than writing the actual game. If you cannot write that  game then you cannot write a cheat for it.

Comment: @IInspectable is there documentation to know input lower level? i read raw input message only works if the target handle that message. but, i suggest no application will handle that message except keylogger application. what u means lower level? there's api?

Comment: You cannot do what you're trying to do from the outside. You'll have to do it from the inside. There is no documentation for any of that. Lot's of reverse engineering required.

Comment: @IInspectable after searching and searching, the possible ways is simulate unlimited cursor by write mouse driver. if i use sendclick. i can't do anything.

Comment: A mouse driver won't help you send input to a program that's not on the screen. As I said previously, cheating is hard.

Comment: @yuiamanda You might hook the window procedure of the main window. That might be an option.

Comment: A hook is an observer. Observing input does not help when the goal is to inject input.

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah, you are right. It wouldn't make the game to process the input. As you said, it requires a lot of reverse engineering.

Comment: @SemihArtan hook window procedure? do you means inject dll into target program? or is it possible to connect my application procedure with target procedure? is like just connect thread?

Comment: @yuiamanda > "It wouldn't make the game to process the input."

Comment: @SemihArtan i see, my postmessage work. it simulates down and up click. but game interface not open. i just decompile and trace what method  called when icon got click. in the end, i cant bypass anti-cheat to call method outside game application. i can easyly change anti-cheat injector dll in game. but i think the game and anti-cheat interconnect each other to check if  client game have been mod or not. what i need to do not to mod the client game. but, run in more high privilege. as i search, all application run in user level. what i need to do make driver that execte func in kernel privilege